# Using sql queries in Business-Data Layered application

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, asp.net-web-api

I'm sorry if exactly same question is somewhere in the haystack of Stack Overflow questions but I've been searching answers for 2 days and at last I'm here. 
Please feel free to mention if there are any duplicates but make sure they address the issue.

I have a very old application where code is not object oriented and sql queries are everywhere to get data and each of then uses sqlcommand/sqldatareader.

Now, I'm trying to move to WCF Web API framework and trying to separate business and data layers. Most of the sql queries return different set of columns.

I believe the sql queries must be executed in data layer. 
I'm building those queries or placing existing queries in Business layer and passing those queries to Data Layer. 
My plan is to return datasets from data layer. Manipulate and put into domain classes in Business layer and return into the controller.

However, I feel this is not a good approach and it's tightly coupled. I cannot find a way to how I should make it loosely coupled. 
If I was to use EF or ORM then I could use DBContext to get data in the Business Layer. 
I cannot map each database table to POCO class in my data layer (because most queries are complex and return different set of columns).

**Question**
How should I deal with the queries to make this architecture a better one in terms of making it loosely coupled?

Comment: I'd take the queries out of your code for a start and add them to stored procedures, so your code would simply call a stored proc to return the same data. The will protect you against sql injection and I believe, although I could be wrong, it would allow sql server to cache the stored proc execution plans to perform better.

Comment: what about the architecture? making the business/data layers loosely coupled?

Answer (score 0):

Fixing up a brownfields project like the one you are dealing with is tricky. It sounds like you have the right idea in terms of trying to get all sql queries into a data layer.
My suggestion is to find a thin slice. A small part of the application (e.g. if the system allows you to add a user) and try to refactor the code into the structure you want. Then find the next thin slice...
Another tip is that you should do one small refactor at a time as soon as you let your refactorings get too big you increase the risk of introducing bugs.

A tool like resharper is a great help when it comes safely refactoring your code.  It does have a bit of a learning curve, but it's worth the effort.

Comment: What architecture or structure of the project would you suggest? Right now I've started with Business Layer which contains models. Models are the classes based on the xml structure I want to return. Then I have data layer which contains repositories and some generic DTOs. Most of the repository is generic. Would you suggest something else?

Comment: As I said your architecture should be fine. I think you should focus on refactoring with the smallest steps possible. If this is a production project you probably want to be working in an area that will add value to the business

Comment: Yes :) It's production project. Thanks a lot